# What is wrong with this agrument

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(e_n)_n$ be the standard basis for $c_0$ and let $t_1,t_2$ be numbers in $[0,1)$. I believe it's generally false that $||t_1e_1+t_2e_2||\leq||e_1+e_2||$, but I thought that I had an argument that showed it was true.

By Hahn Banach, there is an $f\in\ell^1$ with $||f||=1$ and $f(t_1e_1+t_2e_2)=||t_1e_1+t_2e_2||$.  $f(t_1e_1+t_2e_2)=t_1f(e_1)+t_2f(e_2)$. If $f(e_1),f(e_2)\geq 0$, then $t_1f(e_1)+t_2f(e_2)<f(e_1)+f(e_2)=f(e_1+e_2)\leq ||f||||e_1+e_2||=||e_1+e_2||$

Suppose $f(e_1)<0$ and $f(e_2)\geq 0$. Then by defining $F(e_1)=-f(e_1)$ and $F(e_j)=f(e_j)$ for $j\not=1$, we have $||F||=\sum_n|F(e_n)|=\sum_n|f(e_n)|=||f||=1$ and $||t_1e_1+t_2e_2||=t_1f(e_1)+t_2f(e_2)<t_1F(e_1)+t_2F(e_2)=F(t_1e_1+t_2e_2)\leq||F||||t_2e_2+t_1e_1||=||t_2e_2+t_1e_1||$ a contradiction.

I know something is wrong with this argument, I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you use the usual supremum norm on $c_0$.
Then,
$$\|t_1 \, e_1 + t_2 \, e_2\| = \max\{t_1, t_2\} \le 1 = \|e_1 + e_2\|.$$
Hence, your inequality holds true.